# How to remove backslash from exception message in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have this exception message:

```
 public CityDto getCityByName(String name) throws DataNotFoundException {
    CityEntity cityEntity = cityRepository.findByName(name);
    if (cityEntity == null){
        throw new DataNotFoundException("city with name " + '"' + name + '"' + " not found!");
    }else
        return CityMapper.INSTANCE.toCityDto(cityEntity);
}
```

and this how Postman show me this message:

```
{
"status": "NOT_FOUND",
"message": "Entity not found",
"errors": [
    "city with name \"Toronto\" not found!"
]
```

}

As u can see, city name Toronto for some reason have backslash. How to remove it?

Comment: This is due to 'character escaping'. The backslash prevents the quotes around Toronto to terminate the string. Try using single quotes around Toronto

Comment: You can try to remove those backslashes manually from the response and check if your Json would still be valid.

Comment: Those backslashes are expected and are required for well-formed JSON. There is no problem to solve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this `throw new DataNotFoundException("city with name '" + name + "' not found!")`

Answer (score 0):

Removing backslash is not the issue, basically you need to understand the technical details why the backslash is there.

For this you can visit this [Java Strings W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_strings_specchars.asp)  link to understand
as it explains

> Because strings must be written within quotes, Java will misunderstand
> this string, and generate an error:

```
String txt = "We are the so-called "Vikings" from the north.";
```

> The solution to avoid this problem, is to use the backslash escape
> character.
>
> The backslash (\) escape character turns these characters into
> string characters

The sequence \"  inserts a double quote in a string